# Progressive web app not installable not working using craco/typescript and create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, craco

I've a react app which is build using cra and craco/typescript version and i want to add PWA installable in this existing app. How can I do this there is currently no manifest.json, service-worker.js and other related files. this is my index.tsx file

```
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals'; 
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'; 
import App from 'App'; import { DndProvider } from 'react-dnd'; 
import { HTML5Backend } from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render( <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}> <App /> </DndProvider> );

reportWebVitals(); 
console.log(You are using v${process.env.REACT_APP_VERSION}});
```

I tried solution on the web but nothing seems to work please help!